# Не упоминается роль через команду

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Сделала команду для бота в DISCORD, но не работает именно упоминание роли (пинг). Делаю на языке python с библиотекой disnake. (У бота стоят права админа и все разрешения есть.)

Выбор роли в команде осуществляется через упоминание "Role":
`role: disnake.Role = commands.Param(None, name="роль", description="упоминание группировки")):`

А само упоминание вне блока Embed так:
`await interaction.send(f"{role.mention}", embed=embed)`
[image: Это пример, что нету пинга]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо добавить:

```
from disnake import AllowedMentions

await interaction.send(f"{role.mention}", embed=embed, allowed_mentions = AllowedMentions(roles = True))
```

в "await interaction.send" через запятую после "embed=embed"

и в "bot = commands.Bot" добавить "allowed_mentions = disnake.AllowedMentions.all()" так же через запятую.